# Application of Stoke's Law

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

I was looking at [Stoke's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_law) and it says that you use it to calculate the drag force on a sphere passing through a fluid. Can i also use this equation to calculate the drag force on a car going through air (which is a fluid)?

Comment: Stokes' law is for laminar flow, i.e. very low Reynold's numbers/very low velocity. For something the size of a car this may be correct at velocities of small fractions of a mm/s. For typical car velocities you need a drag formula with a quadratic dependence of drag force and velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Other are correct in saying no. In addition to Stoke's law of damping being correct only for spherical objects in laminar flow, there are many other factors that affect the drag of a vehicle.

I'll assume you're talking specifically about aerodynamic drag, which doesn't account for frictional losses due to things like tires and etc. The most obvious source of drag that will ruin this approximation is the region immediately behind block of the vehicle. If not properly accounted for, there is a notorious amount of turbulent air in these zones that increases drag:
[image: Turbulent air zones of a semi-truck]

As another example, consider a high diver jumping into a pool. If they nose dive they will displace the water easily and safely. If they belly flop, they will not displace the water efficiently and probably be in pain because of it.

Stokes law does a great job of approximating spheres, but it could never account for the geometry of a normal car. It is strictly for spheres.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i also use this equation to calculate the drag force on a car going through air (which is a fluid)?

No. Stokes really only applies for perfect spheres and low speeds (laminar flow).

For higher speeds and non-spherical objects [you need to use this approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Drag_at_high_velocity).

Comment: that doesn't really explain how to find $C_D$ though, which is the difficult part

Comment: Not that difficult at all, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient

Comment: that article also doesn't describe how to find $C_D$ for his situation, just a list of example values

Comment: The only *accurate* way to determine $C_D$ is empirically. But to get a good idea of the drag force, an *approx.* value for $C_D$ is sufficient.